# Jenkins "build queue loop" issue

Tags: jenkins

Recently updated Jenkins (2.332.3) got into "build queue loop". Restart is not helping at all as the build queue will appear again out of nowhere.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Check what triggers the builds. You should see something like Started by..... in the console out.

Comment: @ycr it says `started by timer`. No clue form where it came even I have set to scan multibranch pipeline triggers each 1hr when that is added up way fater

Comment: @ycr I think I see what is the problem. On the Organization Folder I have set to that 1hr but on the repo it got set to 1 minute and that value I'm not able to apply after the change.